# Angular use constants in config

Tags: angularjs

Right now I've got this in my route file:

```
employeeAppModule.config([
        '$httpProvider',
        function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {
                var token, headers, $cookies;

                //inject cookies
                angular.injector(['ngCookies']).invoke(['$cookies', function(_$cookies_) {
                    $cookies = _$cookies_;
                }]);

                return {
                    request: function (request) {
                        console.log(request);

                        token = $cookies.get('jwt-token');
                        alert('request' + token);
                        headers = request.headers || (request.headers = {});

                        if(token != null && token != 'undefined') {
                            headers.Authorization = token;
                        }
                        return request;
                    },
                    response: function (response) {
                        if(response.status && response.status.code === 401) {
                            alert('token wordt verwijderd');
                        }

                        if(response.data && response.data.token && response.data.token.length > 10) {
                            $cookieStore.put('jwt-token', 'Bearer ' + response.data.token);
                        }
                        return response;
                    }
                };
            });
        }]);
```

I inject ngCookies manual. Is it also possible to inject globals? How could I do this?

Comment: What kind of 'constants' do you refer to?

Comment: Sorry! I mean Global variables!

Answer (score 0):

The globals are meant to be defined as `constant` (if they have to be injected during config phase) or `value` (if they don't) services:

```
app.value('Global', Global);
```

If the globals aren't available at service definition time, they can be defined as `factory` to be lazily instantiated.

`angular.injector` is the wrong way to get an injector in `config` block (and almost anywhere else). It creates a new injector instance, which is not used anywhere else. In the case of `$cookies` the side effect is untestable piece of code that don't have full test coverage.

[Interceptor factory function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) is DI-enabled, service instances can be injected with

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($cookies, Global) {
  ...
```